# How was this scene in Jurassic World shot?

Tags: film-techniques, stunts, jurassic-world

In Jurassic World, how did they shoot the scene in which Claire's assistant:

> dies by getting picked up by a flying Pteranodon, dropped in a giant water tank, picked up by the Pteranodon again, and then gets chomped by the huge Mosasaurus.
> [image]

Even for well trained stunt-men, being pushed in and out of a pool three four times looks very hard and dangerous.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

The director Colin Trevorrow said it was all real. Well, up to the dinosaur part, they haven't figured out how to get around the [AHA rules.](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/NoAnimalsWereHarmed)

> The stunts for the kill scene were done by [Zara Young's actress Katie McGrath] herself. “She was game,” Trevorrow said. [“That’s really her, that fall, her under the water, that’s really the actress. She completely committed to what I think is one of the all-time dinosaur deaths in a movie.”](https://www.yahoo.com/movies/jurassic-world-death-scene-dimorphodon-pterodactyl-121631328092.html)

The parts where she's being carried have more movie magic than the rest, for obvious reasons, but it's mostly practical effects.

**It's shown in the Behind the Scenes interview with her on the Blu Ray special features.** ([GIF version here](http://fy-katiemcgrath.tumblr.com/post/132809111116/faymcwrath-katie-mcgraths-stunt-in-jurassic))

[image]

#### It's basically bungee jumping into a river. It's a little hard on the body, but quick, and fun. I'd do it in a heart beat if someone was paying me to.

Full safety crew, trained stunt advisers, etc.

It's not much different from how violently the woman in the intro to Jaws gets thrashed around really.

Comment: Wow, they really dropped her instead of just using cables & a green screen? I'm impressed.

Comment: Ah, beat me to it, so upvote for you!

Comment: @Walt the high drop was done on cables and a green screen, er, rug and safety air bag. Once that was done, they moved on for the wet scenes which were done in a blue screen, er, tank. The middle right image of 6, and bottom left, you can't see it well, but there are wires used to pull her up and down, See http://67.media.tumblr.com/55980aa9490f8a5aface4297522c6e6b/tumblr_nxi7gmZi161uehb3mo3_250.gif and http://66.media.tumblr.com/f7d8e65aa2ad883d202c0740caf19c74/tumblr_nxi7gmZi161uehb3mo7_250.gif But I know you mean that it wasn't just done by dangling in air.

Comment: around the APA rules?

Comment: @RedCaio American humane association. Ugh. Typo.